# weird output when partitioning a matrix into lists in R

Tags: r, matrix, functional-programming

I've been trying to write a function that takes in matrix (x) and a vector (cut.vec) and outputs a list, where each element of the list is a combination of some of the columns in the input matrix. Each element in the input vector is an index where want to partition the matrix. Then I want to save every partition to an element in a list and return that list.

Here's what I've got so far:

*This is the actual function that I'm running*:

```
make.cut <- function(x, cut.vec){

    ran.once <- 0 #This checks for first run
    out <- list() #This creates the output list
    temp.matrix <- matrix() #For holding data

    for(i in 1:length(cut.vec)){

        for(n in 1:cut.vec[i]){

            if(cut.vec[i]<n){
                #Do nothing
            }else{
                hold <- x[,n]
                if(ran.once != 0){
                    temp.matrix <- cbind(temp.matrix, hold)
                }else{
                    temp.matrix <- hold
                    ran.once <- 1
                }
            }
        }

        out[[i]] <- temp.matrix
        temp.matrix <- matrix()
    }
    return(out)
}
```

When I run this I get a list out, but only the first element is correct. Each element except the first one only contains one column of the input matrix.

```
**Example Input**
x<-matrix(c(341, 435, 834, 412, 245, 532.2, 683.4, 204.2, 562.7, 721.5, 149, 356, 112, 253, 211, 53, 92, 61, 84, 69), nrow=4)

x= 341   435   834   412   245
   532.2 683.4 204.2 562.7 721.5
   149   356   112   253   211
   53    92    61    84    69

cut.vec = c(2, 3, 5)

out <- make.cut(x, cut.vec):

a <- out[[1]]
b <- out[[2]]
c <- out[[3]]

**Intended Output**
a= 341   435  
   532.2 683.4 
   149   356   
   53    92    

b= 834  
   204.2
   112  
   61   

c= 412   245
   562.7 721.5
   253   211
   84    69

**Actual Output**
a= 341   435   
   532.2 683.4 
   149   356  
   53    92   

b= 435   
   683.4 
   356   
   92    

c= 834  
   204.2
   112  
   61
```

I can do this from the console manually, one element at a time and it works, but every time I try and do it with the make.cut function it breaks.

This is how I did it by hand in terminal:

```
cut.vec<-c(3, 5)

a<-x[,1]
b<-x[,2]
c<-x[,3]

temp <- cbind(a,b,c)

out[[1]] <- temp
```

cut.vec[2] is equal to 5

```
a<-x[,4]
b<-x[,5]

temp <- cbind(a,b)

out[[2]] <- temp
```

However, when I try to apply the same methodology in a function it breaks.

Comment: Since you know the indices, perhaps, you can do something like: `mat = matrix(1:24, nrow = 4)` ; `lapply(list(1:3, 4:5), function(x) as.matrix(mat[,x]))`?

Comment: You could turn `cutvec` to a list of indices with something like: `cutvec = c(6, 8, 17)` ; `.ls <- mapply(":", c(1, cutvec)[-length(c(1, cutvec))], cutvec - 1)` and, then `lapply(.ls, ...)`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg edit.Done. Sorry about that. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: @alexis_laz I tried that, but the problem is that when the function runs it cut at the wrong point except for the first run. I updated the question with sample input and output to make thing clearer. Thanks

Comment: Try this, maybe: `.ls <- mapply(":", c(1, cut.vec+1)[-length(c(1, cut.vec+1))], cut.vec)` ; `lapply(.ls, function(z) as.matrix(x[,z]))`. Also, use `byrow = T` in `x = matrix(...)` to build the `x` you show.

Comment: @Saren The desired output described in the comments does not match the desired output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach to "cut" a matrix along a vector:

Example data:

```
mat <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15
# [2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16

cutvec <- c(2,5)
```

First, cut the column numbers of `mat` along `cutvec`:

```
cuts <- cut(seq(ncol(mat)), c(0, cutvec - 1))
```

Then you can create a list with subsets with `tapply`:

```
tapply(seq(ncol(mat)), cuts, function(x) mat[, x, drop = FALSE])

# $`(0,1]`
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
#
# $`(1,4]`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    5    7
# [2,]    4    6    8
```